# How to trigger a callback when field is changed using reflection in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

For example I want to log the `Name` value every time it changes.

```cs
using System;

class Data {
    public string Name;
    
    public Data(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Data data = new("foo");
        
        object name = typeof(Data).GetField("Name").GetValue(data);
        
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using a property that can then raise an event. You should not be using public fields. Raising change events is one of the main reasons for properties in the first place.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment - checkout/search for [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-7.0). There are options to even generate automatic implementations for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do such thing with a *field*, but you can turn it into *property* and then add a code to track the process. We can add an *event* for convenient tracking:

```
class Data {
    private string m_Name;

    public string Name {
        get => m_Name;
        set {
            // If we don't want to trigger event on each Name assignment
            // but on actual chnages only  
            if (string.Equals(m_Name, value))
                return;  

            // Before Changing
            //TODO: fire event here if you want to track Name just befor changing

            m_Name = value;

            // After Changing
            NameChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); 
        }
    }
    
    public Data(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    // Event thar will be fired on each Name change
    public event EventHandler NameChanged;
}
```

usage:

```
Data myData = new Data("");

// We register event handler
myData.NameChanged += (o, e) => {
  Console.WriteLine($"Name changed into {((Data) o).Name}");
};

// And change the Name which will fire the event
myData.Name = "Some Other Name";
```

Comment: Note that this still will not be able to determine if underlying property is changed by reflection.

Comment: @GuruStron you mean "field" instead of "property", but indeed.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, field of course. Need more coffee =)